# Kafka TOPIC_AUTHORIZATION_FAILED

Tags: apache-kafka, acl, jaas

I'm actually working on setting up simple Kafka authentication using SASL Plain Text and add ACL authorization. But I have an issue when I try to consume data.

```
[main] INFO org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser - Kafka version : 0.10.0.0
[main] INFO org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser - Kafka commitId : b8642491e78c5a13
[main] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 1 : {test-topic=TOPIC_AUTHORIZATION_FAILED}
[main] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 2 : {test-topic=TOPIC_AUTHORIZATION_FAILED}
[main] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 3 : {test-topic=TOPIC_AUTHORIZATION_FAILED}
[main] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 4 : {test-topic=TOPIC_AUTHORIZATION_FAILED}
[main] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 5 : {test-topic=TOPIC_AUTHORIZATION_FAILED}
[main] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 6 : {test-topic=TOPIC_AUTHORIZATION_FAILED}
[main] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 7 : {test-topic=TOPIC_AUTHORIZATION_FAILED}
[main] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 8 : {test-topic=TOPIC_AUTHORIZATION_FAILED}
[main] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 9 : {test-topic=TOPIC_AUTHORIZATION_FAILED}
[main] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 10 : {test-topic=TOPIC_AUTHORIZATION_FAILED}
```

Next, you can see my configuration files.

server.properties

```
listeners=SASL_PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
security.inter.broker.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=PLAIN
sasl.enabled.mechanisms=PLAIN
broker.id=0
num.network.threads=3
num.io.threads=8
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs
num.partitions=1
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
log.retention.hours=168
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
authorizer.class.name=kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer
```

producer.properties

```
security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092
compression.type=none
```

consumer.properties

```
security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
zookeeper.connect=127.0.0.1:2181
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
group.id=test-consumer-group
```

kafka_server_jaas.conf

```
KafkaServer {
  org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
  username="admin"
  password="admin-secret"
  user_admin="admin-secret"
  user_alice="alice-secret";
};

KafkaClient {
  org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
  username="alice"
  password="alice-secret";
};
```

Environment variable:

```
export KAFKA_OPTS="-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/home/user/kafka_2.10-0.10.0.1/kafka_server_jaas.conf"
```

Commands

Set ACL:

```
bin/kafka-acls.sh --authorizer kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer --authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181 --add --allow-principal User:alice --operation All --group test-consumer-group --topic test-topic
```

start Kafka Server :

```
./bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties
```

Start Producer:

```
bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test-topic --producer.config=config/producer.properties
```

Start Consumer:

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --new-consumer --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic test-topic --from-beginning --consumer.config=config/consumer.properties  --bootstrap-server=localhost:9092
```

When I try to start the consumer, I have the issue described above. Also, in the kafka logs, I have this:

```
[2016-10-22 20:17:14,091] ERROR [KafkaApi-0] Error when handling request {group_id=test-consumer-group} (kafka.server.KafkaApis)
kafka.admin.AdminOperationException: replication factor: 3 larger than available brokers: 1
    at kafka.admin.AdminUtils$.assignReplicasToBrokers(AdminUtils.scala:117)
    at kafka.admin.AdminUtils$.createTopic(AdminUtils.scala:403)
    at kafka.server.KafkaApis.kafka$server$KafkaApis$$createTopic(KafkaApis.scala:629)
    at kafka.server.KafkaApis.kafka$server$KafkaApis$$createGroupMetadataTopic(KafkaApis.scala:651)
    at kafka.server.KafkaApis$$anonfun$getOrCreateGroupMetadataTopic$1.apply(KafkaApis.scala:657)
    at kafka.server.KafkaApis$$anonfun$getOrCreateGroupMetadataTopic$1.apply(KafkaApis.scala:657)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at kafka.server.KafkaApis.getOrCreateGroupMetadataTopic(KafkaApis.scala:657)
    at kafka.server.KafkaApis.handleGroupCoordinatorRequest(KafkaApis.scala:818)
    at kafka.server.KafkaApis.handle(KafkaApis.scala:86)
    at kafka.server.KafkaRequestHandler.run(KafkaRequestHandler.scala:60)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Hi, I think, you are trying to access a multi-broker cluster. but, the configuration (server.properties) is just creating a single broker. please check your application code. if you want to create multi (3) broker cluster, create three different configuration files like server-1.properties, server-2.properties and server-3.properties and define three brokers.

Comment: Hi, I'm not trying to access a multi-broker cluster. I already checked my config, I also don't want to create a multi broker cluster.

Comment: Can you please post your application code where you are creating your topics ?

Comment: I don't used any Java code for this. I create it with "bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic test"

Comment: Let me delete all my folders, do a fresh install and test it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue fixed by separating jaas client and jaas server.

**kafka_server_jaas.conf**

```
KafkaServer {
  org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
  username="admin"
  password="admin-secret"
  user_admin="admin-secret"
  user_alice="alice-secret";
};
```

**kafka_client_jaas.conf**

```
KafkaClient {
  org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
  username="alice"
  password="alice-secret";
};
```

On the same terminal, export jaas server conf file and start kafka broker:

```
$ export KAFKA_OPTS="-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/home/user/kafka_2.10-0.10.0.1/kafka_server_jaas.conf"
$ ./bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties
```

On a client terminal, export client jaas conf file and start consumer:

```
$ export KAFKA_OPTS="-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/home/user/kafka_2.10-0.10.0.1/kafka_client_jaas.conf"
$ ./bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --new-consumer --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic test-topic --from-beginning --consumer.config=config/consumer.properties  --bootstrap-server=localhost:9092
```

If you also want to produce, do this on another terminal window:

```
$ export KAFKA_OPTS="-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/home/user/kafka_2.10-0.10.0.1/kafka_client_jaas.conf"
$ ./bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test-topic --producer.config=config/producer.properties
```

Answer (score 1):

I have faced similar issue with using the ACLs in Kafka v.0.10. I found this discussion helpful. Especially enabling the authorization log in order to check what is the incoming username for the request and what is it specified in your ACLs. 
Firstly check if the server principal *admin* is provided all the authorization needed. Server principal needs to be allowed to perform all types of authorization on all topics, groups as well as cluster. It's better to declare the *admin* in the super-users in server.properties file. If this doesn't resolve the issue, then you can enable the authorization log to find out which specimen is being deined for what operation. 
Authorization log can be enabled by modifying the log4j.properties in the config folder. In log4j.properties file, change `WARN` to `DEBUG` and restart the kafka-servers.

```
log4j.logger.kafka.authorizer.logger=DEBUG, authorizerAppender
```

This helped me in sorting out my issue. Hope that helps.

PS: The authorization logs generated will be very lengthy and consume a lot of space. So, remember to turn this off when done with debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have created a topic with replication factor of 3 but you only have 1 broker running. Try creating a topic with "--replication-factor 1". You might also want to change the default replication factor to be 1 (default.replication.factor in config/server.properties) if you are creating topics automatically.

Comment: Thank you for the response but I created the topic manually with a replication factor of 1. I still had the same issue.

Comment: I don't have any issue on the topic creation but I still have the same issue on the terminal which launch the kafka server. kafka.admin.AdminOperationException: replication factor: 3 larger than available brokers: 1

Comment: Let me delete all my folders, do a fresh install and test it again